# Django Decorator Order signals

Tags: python, django, signals, decorator

I was reading a tutorial for signaling in django and I came across an example

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
  def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
      Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
  def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

How do we chose the order or operations?

How do we know create_user_profile execs before save_user_profile?

If order is decided by declaration , isn't it a bit dangerous when code is merged automatically via git or svn or whatever.

Comment: Can't you just make two separate methods and run them in the order you want in single post_save?

Comment: I did and it is working actually. I think it registers it in the order the code is parsed. I always get it in the right order, I ran a test for 1000 times. The order is always correct.
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

I think under the hood it does this.

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
post_save.connect(save_user_profile, sender=User)
But not sure. It is new to me too.